# how to check multiple OR condition with variable number of arguments

Tags: javascript

I was checking if a number of input tag is empty or not by

```
if(inputValue1.length === 0 || inputValue2.length === 0 || 
   inputValue3.length === 0 || inputValue4.length === 0)
```

but the more I code, I find out that i have to check if variable number of `input` tag is empty or not several times.

Since above code is hard coded which it only checks 4 `input` tag values, I wanted to make a function which checks conditions, of variable number of arguments given (giving `input` tag elements), by OR operator. For example:

```
checkEmptyInput(multiple_elements){}
```

making it possible to pass multiple and random of arguments but still checks condition with OR operator. I can't think how I would complete that function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thx for your opinion :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yup wrote it above that "checks 4 input tag values"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list. For instance, if all your inputs are in some container (say, a `form`), you can get all of them as a list using `querySelectorAll`:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("selector-for-the-form input");
```

That returns a collection with a `length` and where each `input` is available via `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. So:

```
function checkEmptyInput(list) {
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        if (list[0].value.length === 0) {
            return true; // There's an empty one
        }
    }
    return false; // There are no empty ones
}
```

Comment: thank you ! i feel so dumb that i couldnt have thought of that :(

Comment: This is a great answer. As an adon, it will be more efficient if the function is returning you the name which field was not validated. I have written the function if you would like to check as an addon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```js
var   input1 = [1, 2]
    , input2 = [1, 2]
    , input3 = [2, 1];

function test(...args) {
  return args.some(function(arg) {
    return arg.length === 0;
  });
};

var result1 = test(input1, input2, input3);
var result2 = test([], input1, input2);

console.log(result1, result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the variables to a function that reduces over its arguments:

ES2015 version:

```
function checkEmptyInput(...multiple_elements) {
    return multiple_elements.reduce((a,b) => a || b, false);
}
```

ES5 version:

```
function checkEmptyInput() {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a,b) { return a || b; }, false);
}
```

Use it as you described

```
checkEmptyInput(variable1, variable2, variable3);
```

Answer (score 0):

0You need to have a function which is generic and can take any number of arguments and can return you an error :

Below function will take a callback and n number of arguments. Callback function will return 2 params, first is status true or false and second is message if status is false.

```
function validateAll(callback, ...inputs){
    var len = inputs.length;
  for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
    if(inputs[i].value.length === 0){
        return callback(false, inputs[i].getAttribute('name') + 'Input not valid');
    }
  }
  return callback(true, null);
}

validateAll(function(status, msg){
    console.log(status, msg);
},input1,input2, input3);
```